# Get parameter from last iteration with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

How to perform  this without iteration, with LINQ?

```
 string[] flatSource = {"region1", "subregion1", 
                        "region2", "sub1", "sub2", 
                        "region3", "sub1", "sub2"};

 string previousRegion = "";
 foreach (var item in flatSource)
 {
    if (SomeRegionDictionary.Contains(item))
       previousRegion = item;  //This is what I can't figure out 
    else
       yield return new SubregionWithRegion{Region = previousRegion, SubRegion = item};
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current solution is fine; LINQ isn't the ideal choice for such stateful queries.
Here's a pure-LINQ solution though; it's not ideal because it is a little cryptic *and* has quadratic complexity, but is functionally equivalent:

```
return flatSource.Select((item, index) => 
                     new SubregionWithRegion
                     {
                       Region = flatSource.Take(index + 1)
                                          .LastOrDefault(SomeRegionDictionary.ContainsKey) ?? "",
                       SubRegion = item
                     })
                  .Where(srwr => !SomeRegionDictionary.ContainsKey(srwr.SubRegion));
```

The stateful nature of the loop is handled with the `Take` + `LastOrDefault` queries, and the tricky `else` condition is handled by the final `Where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that i didn't read the question carefully enough. So the extension below might be useful, but not to this question.

```
public static class IEnumerableOfTExtensions
{
    public static T Before<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        if (condition == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("condition");

        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var first = true;
            var before = default(T);

            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                if (condition(e.Current))
                {
                    if (first)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("condition", "The first element corresponds to the condition.");

                    return before;
                }

                first = false;
                before = e.Current;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("condition", "No element corresponds to the condition.");
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the final query come anywhere close to solving the OP's original question?

Comment: @Ani: You're right. I just didn't read the question carefully enough. So i let my answer here, but yours seem to solve the concrete problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could find the [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb548744.aspx) method useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one statement with Zip in Net 4.0:

```
return
 flatSource.Where(i=>SomeRegionDictionary.Contains(i)).Zip(arr.Skip(1),
  (first, second) => new SubregionWithRegion{Region = first, SubRegion = second});
```

If you don't have Net 4.0, you can use this implementation: [Zip Me Up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx)